# Core Data & Asset Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm starting a new project (and very new to Core Data) and was curious about how to manage images within Core Data and an Asset Library. I've done some reading and am just unclear on how everything works together.

Is it possible for each Managed Object to have an "asset library" of images? ie. can the asset library be populated with Core Data data.

What is the best way to handle having a large array of images attached to a managed object?

If anyone can point me in a direction of an article/tutorial or provide further guidance, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Core Data can handle storing an image asset database as well as the images themselves.  Core Data has an option that will let it store large binary objects as files, rather than in the sqlite database itself.  Core Data would be effective for storing details about the images and for categorising them into albums, projects etc..  It would also be useful for searching on these attributes.

Typically you would not attach a large array of images to a managed object.  An image would be represented by a managed object and one of the attributes of the managed object would be the image (which Core Data might decide to store as a file somewhere).

I think you might be out of luck if you want to use iCloud for replicating this image library because I don't think Core Data will sync these externally stored image files.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5.html

Managed objects support two significant new features: ordered relationships, and external storage for attribute values. If you specify that the value of a managed object attribute may be stored as an external record, Core Data heuristically decides on a per-value basis whether it should save the data directly in the database or store a URI to a separate file that it manages for you.

Comment: I did some reading and somewhere someone had said a good approach for storing images was to save them to the file system and then store the path in Core Data - would you recommend this?

Answer (score 0):

if you store your images in image assets and Managed Object have the "asset library" of images, then you will have the problem on updating the images. 
and even if you do not want to ever update the images then why to store it in core data ?
solution is : have the images in image assets and also store the binary data of images in core data in launching the app.

- by checking a date of modified coming from a web server you can check whether to update the images or not.

[this link](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data/) is helping you to import anything to core data easily done.